# What would be the best design by OOP to add a new requirement functionality

Tags: c#, oop, solid-principles

So I am facing some design issue and I am not sure how to solve it.

Let's say we have this code
    objectA.UserId;

```
objectA.ValueOne = new DerivedServiceOne().Calculate(values);
objectA.ValueTwo = new DerivedServiceTwo().Calculate(values);
objectA.ValueThree = new DerivedServiceThree().Calulate(values)
```

These services sharing the same interface IBaseService.

Somewhere down the line comes a new requirement that ever valueTwo calculation I should send to FirebaseNotification by passing userId. As well in _notificationService I have some additional logic because sometimes I don't send ValueTwo (business logic)

```
objectA.ValueOne = new DerivedServiceOne().Calculate(values);
objectA.ValueTwo = new DerivedServiceTwo().Calculate(values);
_notificationService.ValidateValueTwoAndPush(userId, objectA.ValueTwo)

objectA.ValueThree = new DerivedServiceThree().Calulate(values)
```

What are the best solutions? I don't want to break the Open/Close principle. I can try to put all that logic into DerivedServiceTwo (with new dependencies) but then I will break LSP as well an additional parameter in
Calculate method appears (userId) and it breaks SRP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I am never one to get caught up on all this OOP. Generally, I'll implement logic where it needs to go and then abstract/refactor; rather than worrying about what principles I may or may not satisfy.

Nonetheless, it seems like you what you want is to provide a mechanism for any service to trigger a Firebase notification based on some event. I'm going to make the assumption that you might want to add in different notification services later, so I'll tailor my answer to that specification.

Keeping OOP in mind, our primary concern should be to encapsulate the logic of the notification service. Furthermore, we want the service to trigger the notification independent of the client code (i.e. the client shouldn't have to call the `_notificationService.ValidateValueTwoAndPush` method.

Suppose that we have a notification service class that faciliates all communication between our app and the various notification services. A barebones definition of this class might be:

```cs
public class NotificationService
{
    public void Trigger(object value, NotificationServiceType serviceDestination)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

where the `Trigger` method sends a notification with the specified `value` to the destination specfiied by the `serviceDestination` parameter. The implementation of the `Trigger` method can be as complex or simple as you want; however, what is important is that you have some mechanism for triggering notifications—via the `NotificationService` class.

We now need some way of passing the notification service into the rest of our services. One way, perhaps the simplest, is to make `NotificationService` a singleton. This is great if you'll only ever have one but if you need to make more than one, this is not an ideal solution.

Another way is to pass the service into all services that require it. This might be done by creating an abstract class that requires that a `NotificationService` is passed into the constructor.

```cs
public abstract class NotificationSender
{
    protected NotificationService NotificationServiceInstance { get; private set; }

    public NotificationSender(NotificationService notificationService)
    {
        NotificationServiceInstance = notificationService;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Finally, all your services can inherit from this abstract class if they wish to send notifications. In doing so, they will be required to call the `NotificationSender` base constructor.

```cs
public class FooService : NotificationSender, IBaseService
{
    public FooService(...parameters, NotificationService notificationService)
        : base(notificationService)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // ...
        // Sometime I want to send a notification...
        NotificationServiceInstance.Trigger(...);
    }
}
```

Of course, you can get really complex with this idea. However, this is a basic OOP idea that should help you clean up the code.

Comment: What would be a complex idea? I am interested in other solutions as well.

Comment: @Andrius A more complex version of this would be to introduce a sort of global messaging system where notifications are triggered via an event (tagged as a notification trigger event) that is then handled by the notification service.

Or as for another example, you could setup a notification service factory that is then used whenever you need to trigger an event.

Comment: But in this example where should I put  'userId' ? With current, your solution client doesn't change any code and the class who calculates value inherits notification abstract class, but where userId I should put? I can not add userId on the method parameter without modifying client (putting additional property userId on Calculate method).

Comment: Depends on whether that data will change. If it doesn't, you can pass it in the constructor of the notification service class. If it is changing, you'll need to he passing it in as a parameter.